# Intercept Email Before Sent by Pastel

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Sage Pastel Evolution is unable to send emails in HTML format.

I am trying to intercept email before it is sent, add information to the subject and body in HTML format.

I placed the following in the `ThisOutlookSession` module:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    
Public Sub Initialize_Handler()
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
End Sub
    
Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sPrompt As String
      
    sPrompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"
    If MsgBox(sPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Nothing seems to be happening when I send an email, neither through Evolution nor through Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remove everything and try just the following code, make sure to restart Outlook before testing*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim prompt As String

    prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.subject & "?"

    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this format, you have to run Initialize_Handler.

If you wish, instead of running it manually, you could do this when Outlook starts.

In the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup
    Initialize_Handler
End Sub
```